# fwrite no escribe en archivo C

Tags: c, archivo

tengo un problema con un programa que estoy escribiendo.

Lo que intento es abrir un archivo escrito en binario con datos de cuentas, este incluye una cabecera con información de los datos que contiene.
Lo que estoy haciendo es leer ese archivo y los datos escribirlos en otro archivo, así como un backup.

Muestro una pequeña parte del codigo:

```
typedef struct _Data{
 long id;
 char nombre[50];
 char email[50];
 char cuenta[10];
 float saldo;
 char estatus;;
}Data;
```

typedef struct _Header{
 long filesize;
 long datasize;
 short offsetData;
 short headerSize;
 short regSize;
 char type[4];
}Header;

void* codigoHilo(void *param){

`altas = fopen("Files/alta.bd","rb");

base = fopen("Files/Banco.bd","wb+");

rewind(altas);

fread(&header,1,sizeof(header),altas);

for(i=1;i<=(header.datasize/header.regSize);i++){

fread(&elementos,1,sizeof(Data),altas);

fwrite(&elementos,1,sizeof(Data),base);

printf("Dada de alta cuenta: %s \n",elementos.cuenta);
}`

Al ejecutarlo lee sin problema el archivo, pero no escribe nada en el archivo banco. Al terminar la ejecución queda un archivo de 0 bytes creado.

Alguien me puede ayudar a retomar el camino.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Salvador. Tu programa no compila. Uno de los errores que da por ejemplo es que no está definida la variable altas. Al formular una pregunta por favor asegúrate de que el código que pones al menos compile. Aunque te hemos respondido a esta pregunta por ser la primera en el futuro te puedes encontrar con que se cierre la pregunta si no cumples un mínimo de calidad. Véase : [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejando aparte el hecho de que tu programa no compila.
Tu programa funciona bien si hay datos de entrada.

He creado datos de entrada con el siguiente programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void creaDatos()
{
    FILE* altas; 
    altas = fopen("Files/alta.bd","wb");
    Header header;
    Data datos;
    header.regSize = sizeof(Data);
    header.datasize = sizeof(Data)*50;
    fwrite( &header, sizeof(header), 1, altas);
    Data data;
    for (int n=0; n<50; ++n)
    {
        data.id = n;
        sprintf(data.nombre, "Jose%d", n);
        sprintf(data.email, "jose@j.com%d", n);
        sprintf(data.cuenta, "CC%d", n);
        data.saldo = 1000*n;
        data.estatus = 'A';
        fwrite( &data, sizeof(data), 1, altas);
    }
    fclose(altas);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    creaDatos();
}
```

Al programa anterior hay que añadirle los tipos de datos apropiados, es decir , las mismas estructuras definidas en la pregunta, no lo repito aquí para no alargarlo innecesariamente.

Disponiendo del fichero *Files/alta.bd* creado con el programa anterior paso a ejecutar el programa de la pregunta con ligeras correcciones para que compile:

```
void* codigoHilo(void *param){
    FILE* altas;
    FILE* base;
    Data elementos;

    altas = fopen("Files/alta.bd","rb");

    base = fopen("Files/Banco.bd","wb+");

    rewind(altas);

    Header header;

    fread(&header,1,sizeof(header),altas);

    for(int i=1;i<=(header.datasize/header.regSize);i++){

        fread(&elementos,1,sizeof(Data),altas);

        fwrite(&elementos,1,sizeof(Data),base);

        printf("Dada de alta cuenta: %s \n",elementos.cuenta);
    }
}
```

Y funciona bien. Crea un fichero *Files/Banco.bd* que es una copia del anterior salvo por la cabecera.

Comment: Gracias, amigo. Ya funciono.  El problema era que no cerraba los archivos con 'fclose()' .No puse el código completo, es por eso de la compilada, pero ahora ya se que debe postear con código que compile. Gracias de nuevo.